# Filter out data that contains a certain text

Tags: excel, vba

How can I **filter** for data that does not contain "ABC", "XYZ" & "DEF"?

For example Column N has the data below

ABC
XYZ K
XYZ
VAN
BUS

I would like the data to keep filters only for **VAN & BUS** as a
result

VBA:

```
Sub Filter()

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

.AutoFilter Field:14, Criteria1:= _ "<>*ABC*", Operator:=xlAnd Criteria2:= _ "<>*XYZ*", Operator:=xlAnd Criteria3:= _ "<>*DEF*"
```

Comment: AutoFilter only allows for 2 values when not using exact values (ie. "contains")

Comment: You can do it by formula.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of an extra column for filtering like this (assuming your data is in column 1 and is labeled or in other words begins on row 2 and column 2 is empty):

[Output before autofilter is applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm6VT.png)

[Output after autofilter is applied via code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfcLy.png)

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("ABC", "XYZ", "DEF")
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each a In arr
            'If a cell contains: ABC, XYZ or DEF, place an x next to it in the 2nd column
            If InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, a) > 0 Then ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "x": Exit For
        Next
    Next
    If ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then ws.Rows(1).AutoFilter 'Check if AutoFilter is enabled, if not then turn it on
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" 'Filter for blanks (filter out 'x' in the second column)
End Sub
```